# Como coloco uma legenda/texto embaixo de uma figura que está dentro de uma tabela no LaTeX?

Tags: latex

Gostaria de colocar uma legenda/texto abaixo de uma figura que está dentro de uma tabela no LaTeX.

Como eu quero...
[image: Tabela Google Docs]

Como está...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou querendo colocar.. (a) NTFS — Leitura aleatória ...

Segue o código

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Vazão de R/W aleatória dos FS em um SSD}
\label{tab-VazaoSSD}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}IOzone Benchmark (File size: 1 GiB, Record length: 4096 KiB)\\
\textbf{Vazão (KiByte/s)}

\end{tabular}} \\ \hline


\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{figuras/ImagensIOZONE/VazaoRW/SSDNTFSLeituraAle.png}

&

\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{figuras/ImagensIOZONE/VazaoRW/SSDNTFSEscritaAle.png}


\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: E qual é seu código LaTeX desta tabela?

Comment: Adicionado, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

É só você colocar `\caption{insira sua legenda aqui}` depois do `\end{tabular}`. Se não me engano é da própria biblioteca do *LaTeX*.

Answer (score 0):

Basta você criar uma linha da tabela com os dados da legenda. Copie este trecho e coloque antes do includegraphics: `(a) NTFS-Leitura aleatória & (b)NTFS-Escrita aleatória \hline \\`

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).